# Cognito not running custom auth challenge

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-cognito

I have created in Cognito the following custom challenge triggers in Python. They are identical to the AWS ones but written in Python.

Define auth challenge:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if (len(event['request']['session']) == 1 and event['request']['session'][0]['challengeName'] == "SRP_A"):
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False
        event['response']['challengeName'] = "PASSWORD_VERIFIER"
    elif (len(event['request']['session']) == 2 and event['request']['session'][1]['challengeName'] == "PASSWORD_VERIFIER" and event['request']['session'][1]['challengeResult'] is True):
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False
        event['response']['challengeName'] = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE"
    elif (len(event['request']['session']) == 3 and event['request']['session'][2]['challengeName'] == "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE" and event['request']['session'][2]['challengeResult'] is True):
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False
        event['response']['challengeName'] = "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE"
    elif (len(event['request']['session']) == 4 and event['request']['session'][3]['challengeName'] == "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE" and event['request']['session'][3]['challengeResult'] is True):
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = True
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = False
    else:
        event['response']['issueTokens'] = False
        event['response']['failAuthentication'] = True

    return event
```

Create auth-challenge:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['request']['challengeName'] != "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE":
        return event

    if len(event['request']['session']) == 2:
        event['response']['publicChallengeParameters'] = {}
        event['response']['privateChallengeParameters'] = {}
        event['response']['publicChallengeParameters']['captchaUrl'] = "url/123.jpg"
        event['response']['privateChallengeParameters']['answer'] = "5"

    if len(event['request']['session']) == 3:
        event['response']['publicChallengeParameters'] = {}
        event['response']['privateChallengeParameters'] = {}
        event['response']['publicChallengeParameters']['securityQuestion'] = "Who is your favorite team mascot?"
        event['response']['privateChallengeParameters']['answer'] = "Peccy"

    return event
```

And verify auth challenge:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['request']['privateChallengeParameters']['answer'] == event['request']['challengeAnswer']:
        event['response']['answerCorrect'] = True
    else:
        event['response']['answerCorrect'] = False

    return event
```

I also added to the Cognito User Pool Client authorization flow the permission: `ALLOW_CUSTOM_AUTH`.

And then I created the following Python client to test my custom Lambdas:

```py
import boto3
from pycognito import AWSSRP

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="aws-profile")
cognito = session.client('cognito-idp')

cognito_user_pool_id = "xx-xxxx-x_xxxxxxxxx"
cognito_user_pool_client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
username = "xxxx"
password = "xxxx"

aws_srp = AWSSRP(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    pool_id=cognito_user_pool_id,
    client_id=cognito_user_pool_client_id,
    client=cognito
)

print("\nInitiate CUSTOM_AUTH with SRP_A challenge")
auth_params = aws_srp.get_auth_params()
resp = cognito.initiate_auth(
    AuthFlow='CUSTOM_AUTH',
    AuthParameters={**auth_params, **{
        "CHALLENGE_NAME": "SRP_A"
    }},
    ClientId=cognito_user_pool_client_id
)
print(resp)

print("\nRespond to PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge")
assert resp["ChallengeName"] == "PASSWORD_VERIFIER"
challenge_response = aws_srp.process_challenge(resp["ChallengeParameters"], auth_params)
resp = cognito.respond_to_auth_challenge(
    ClientId=cognito_user_pool_client_id,
    ChallengeName="PASSWORD_VERIFIER",
    ChallengeResponses={**challenge_response}
)
print(resp)
```

However when I run this code I get the access and ID tokens.

It's worth mentioning the `define auth challenge` lambda function is executing fine for the `SRP_A` flow. The issue is that after I send back the `PASSWORD_VERIFIER` I was expecting to receive the first CUSTOM_CHALLENGE I have defined, but instead I'm the tokens.

Does anybody know what that could be?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, that's not given in the AWS documentation.

When responding back to Cognito via `respond_to_auth_challenge`, if I pass the `Session` paramater, then it invokes the next stage of the custom authentication flow.

```py
# previous code ...

# Respond to PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge
print("\nRespond to PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge")
challenge_response = aws_srp.process_challenge(resp["ChallengeParameters"], auth_params)
resp = cognito.respond_to_auth_challenge(
    ClientId=cognito_user_pool_client_id,
    ChallengeName="PASSWORD_VERIFIER",
    ChallengeResponses={**challenge_response},
    Session=resp["Session"]
)
print(resp)
```